# Print key of hash of arrays if any element of the array matches with another array

Tags: perl

I've an array like this:

```
my @arr = (5, 76, 1000, 21, 47);
```

And this hash:

```
my %hash = (
      Meta => [1000],
);
```

If any of the values of the hash matches any of the elements of the array, I want to print the key value of that match. For doing this, I'm using the following function, and it works:

```
my ($match) = grep { "@{$hash{$_}}" ~~ @arr } keys %hash;
```

The problem comes when I have more than one element in the hash of arrays, for example:

```
my %hash = (
      Meta => [1000, 2],
);
```

In this case, I also want to return the key ("Meta") since the value 1000 is in the array, but I don't get it.

Comment: Is it always a hash of one element called 'Meta' or is that just one example of the elements in the hash?

Comment: Obligatory FYI: as of Perl 5.18.0, [smartmatch is experimental](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#The-smartmatch-family-of-features-are-now-experimental): "It is clear that smartmatch is almost certainly either going to change or go away in the future. Relying on its current behavior is not recommended."

Comment: Use of the smartmatch operator (`~~`) is discouraged. Probably you just need to loop over the hash values.

Comment: @AdamTaylor it's just an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `intersect` from [Array::Utils](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Utils#intersect) to do that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Array::Utils 'intersect';

my @arr = (5, 76, 1000, 21, 47);
my %hash = (
      Meta => [1000, 2],
      Foo  => [1, 2, 3],
      Bar  => [47],
);

my @match = grep { intersect(@{$hash{$_}}, @arr) } keys %hash;

p @match;
```

This prints:

```
[
    [0] "Bar",
    [1] "Meta"
]
```

Note I changed `$match` to `@match` to accomodate more than one key, so I can show match and non-match examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect. I didn't know this module :).

Answer (score 5):

The following will be faster than Array::Utils's `intersect` because it only builds `%set1` once (instead of once per element of `%groups`):

```
my @set1 = (5, 76, 1000, 21, 47);
my %set1 = map { $_ => 1 } @set1;

my %groups = (
   Meta => [1000, 2],
   Foo  => [1, 2, 3],
   Bar  => [47],
);

my @matches = grep { 
    my $set2 = $groups{$_};
    grep { $set1{$_} } @$set2
} keys %groups;
```

For large groups, you might want to use a short-circuiting loop instead of the inner `grep`, but `grep` should be faster for small groups.

Comment: or just `my @matches = grep { grep { $set1{$_} } @{$groups{$_}} } keys %groups;` (though personally I would always stick a sort in there; I don't like arbitrary order)